# How can I have all accounts data in one page?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there any way to have data of all accounts in a single page?
I mean how I can have my questions in Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, Philosophy.SE, etc. on a single page?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/users/4612191/thegooduser?tab=activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible

If you scroll down from your SO profile page(or any other account of SE),you will see "x accounts" along with your accounts of some of the sites. Clicking `view more` button under the 5 accounts will redirect you to [the page you want to see](http://www.stackexchange.com/users/4612191/thegooduser?tab=accounts).

If you have less than 6 accounts ,then the `view more` button will not be there. In such cases, pressing the "x accounts" will show the required page(Thx to @CodyGray for telling this)

Comment: You can also click the "x accounts" header.

Comment: @CodyGray , Ah. I did not know that !

Comment: I usually just use the "network profile" button in the top right of your profile, right below the "ask question" button. Less scrolling.

Comment: @Doorknob But then you have to click a second time on the "accounts" tab. Oh, decisions, decisions!